# how to combine bing map and list view?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, bing-maps, winrt-xaml

i have a bing map in my application. All stored locations from my db are displayed on map as pushpins. On the right of the map i have a list of this positions. What do I need to do to change the color of pushpin on the map after clickng the position on the list view ?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need some kind of data to link the list item to the pushpin. If you have a unique ID value to can store this as an attribute of your list item (Tag property works well). You can also store the ID value in the Tag property of the pushpin.

Then, when you want to set the selected pushpin, loop through all the pushpins on the map and check for the correct, id in the tag property. want to set the background color of the pushpins to the default value you want, and when you find the pushpin with the matching id, set the background color to the highlighting color.